# How to make play music button in Android?

Tags: android

Just to specify the question a little more, I will give an example.  I have a car stereo and when I get in the car I can just press play and it plays the last song I was listening to on my phone.  So what I need is like a very general Android button that does just that.  I just want this button to start media.  It's difficult to explain but I know like Google Music when you open it always has a song at the bottom that you can press play.  So it's kind of like just continuing a previous queue?  If more details are needed please let me know.  Sorry I do not have any code for this problem because I have never worked with media but if you would like the source to my app that this code will go into please visit
    http://mellowdev.net
The app is called Mango.  Open source.

EDIT: I have tried the following but nothing plays.

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
int position = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
mediaPlayer.seekTo(position);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you want to play the music from last known position (or better say from the last known time of the sound). It's something similar like the user change the orientation then you want to play the sound from current position and don't want to start the sound again.

Therfore you have two method in the `MediaPlayer`:

```
int position = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
mediaPlayer.seekTo(position):
```

I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860855/android-videoview-history-bookmark) will help you (the example is for a `VideoView`, but it should be similar to the `MediaPlayer`).

Hope this will help you :)

**EDIT (2013 08 16)**

```
// create a MediaPlayer Instance with the sound you want to play
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, mySound);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need, but I have edited the OP with the code I tried and no sound / music played.

Comment: Did you create the right instance of the `MediaPlayer`. See the answer above, I updated it. Also the position you want to `seekTo` should saved persistent to a file or in a database (Storage Options of android: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). But first you could try to create a `MediaPlayer` with a sound and `seekTo` a predefined position, just to know if this work. Let me know if this worked for you :)

Comment: Got this to work!  Thanks again for all the help, is there anyway to save the last song as an android preference instead of to a file or database?

Answer (score 0):

I couldnt't exactly understand your code. But if you need to play media in android, you need to create instance of MediaPlayer and can start to play using a button. Below link will give you more insight:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html

Sorry if I mis understood your question.

To just launch music player:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MUSIC_PLAYER);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer and this does help, but I see in an example MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_file_1);
mediaPlayer.start();  My problem is that I do not know what the song is that will be playing.  I want it to just start the song in their default music player.  It's not necesarrily a random song but it should just continue playing music from wherever they left off at an earlier time.  So like continuing a "Now Playing" queue.  Thanks!

Comment: You can then just launch the music player from your application using intent. Just edited my answer for that. Check it

Comment: Thank you for the edit, but I don't want the music player to open, just to start playing.